# Как проверять парль по password_hash?

Tags: php, password-hash

Делаю вход в админку. Пароль хеширован `password_hash`. Принимаю данные с формы для входа в админку и тоже хеширую их:

```
$login_admin->password = password_hash("$login_admin->password",PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Этот хеш передается в модель. И запрос не срабатывает из-за разного хеша. Подскажите что я делаю не так? Не пойму как сравнить хешированный пароль если он каждый раз меняется.

```
public function checkAdmin($login_admin)
{
    $q = "SELECT name, password FROM users 
          WHERE name = '$login_admin->nickname' AND password = '$login_admin->password'";
    $res = $this->query($q);

    return $res;
}
```

и

```
$login_admin = new stdClass();
        $login_admin->nickname = Request::post('nickname','string');
        $login_admin->password = Request::post('password','string');

        $checkAdmin = $this->model->checkAdmin($login_admin);
        $data['checkAdmin'] = $checkAdmin;
```

Comment: Конструкция вида - "$login_admin->password", скорее всего воспринимается как текст, зачем вы вообще обернули обращение к свойству в кавычки? Или это и есть пароль?

Answer (score 2):

Есть функция для проверки

```
$pass=password_hash(123, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if(password_verify(123, $pass){...}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74a9d9267e912eea341994846f9bb54900f7926a)

После дополнения вопроса:

Выбирайтей из базы по нику пользователя, сравнивайте пароль в php:

```
public function getAdmin($login_admin)
{
    $q = "SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE name = '{$login_admin->nickname}'";
    $res = $this->query($q);
    if($res && password_verify($login_admin->password, $res->password)){
        return $res;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

if(($admin=$this->model->getAdmin($login_admin))){...}
```

Comment: так у меня проверяется в моделе в самом запросе.`$q = "SELECT name, password FROM users 
              WHERE name = '$login_admin->nickname' AND password = '$login_admin->password'";`

Comment: @Andrii вы неправильно делаете, делайте так, как написано в этом ответе

Comment: У меня больше вопросов чем ответов для вас, что за модель? что за запрос, что куда передается? Зачем хешируете на входе с формы, а не передаете данные в модель и не проверяете с помощью password_verify?

Comment: Зачем вы пихаете пароль в запрос? Выбирите пользователя по нику и проверьте пароль в php.

Comment: знач нужен еще запрос что бы вытащить по нику хеш пароля с бд и потом уже проверять да ? Первый раз делаю вход в админку, не знаю как правильно реализуется, потому и логика дурацкая получается.

Comment: @Andrii зачем, вытаскивайте одновременно ник и хеш и проверяйте

Comment: @Andrii дополнил ответ, просто привел как вариант все в одной функции, можете сделать как либо иначе

Comment: в моделе false возвращает.